# Maintaining the position of div after matrix() in CSS

Tags: css, css-position

How do you maintain the position of div after the matrix() function?

Below is my code

```
<style>

    #div1{
      background: red; 
      width: 150px; 
      height: 150px;
    }

    #div2{
      background: green; 
      transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
 </style>


<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">Lorem Ipsum es un texto de marcador de posición comúnmente utilizado en las industrias gráficas, gráficas y editoriales para previsualizar diseños y maquetas visuales.</div>
<div>
```

As you can see, I am using matrix() css funciton to try to scale my text.

This is my default value: `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`
And this is the result I am getting.

[image]

And once I edited the 4th value with `matrix(1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0);`, I get this result, the text suddenly shifted to lower.
[image]

My goal is to maintain the text's position at the top:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

This solves the problem

```
transform-origin: left top;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Matrix()` method of 6 values and the last parameter is what you have to modify to get his fixed.

More info on matrix():

[Link-1](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/)

[Link-2](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_matrix)

```css
#div1 {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#div2 {
  background: green;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, -40);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">Lorem Ipsum es un texto de marcador de posición comúnmente utilizado en las industrias gráficas, gráficas y editoriales para previsualizar diseños y maquetas visuales.</div>
  <div>
```

Comment: What us the relation between the 4th value and the 6th value. I want it to be more responsive, if I input different length of text, I would constantly have to change it. I want the user to put their own text and I want to maintain the position

Comment: It is and 2D elements, like if you have an matrix array something like this matrix(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) = then it will be of 3 columns and the numbers will be 1&2, 3&4, and 5&6, unfortunately I cannot add the content here, however I can add the link in the answer for reference.

Comment: What I meant was, how did you come up with -40 as a value? If I change the 4th value to something like 0.6 what value you're gonna put on the 6th parameter? Like what is the formula between these two values to maintain its position to top? You explain it with javascript I don't mind

Comment: @PhilGreene I have added a couple URL which may give you some inputs, I strongly suggest to go through the functionality before implementing anything.

Comment: @PhilGreene if you check the second URL from w3schools, it will give you clear picture of how the content behave based on changing the numbers. When we talk about 2D element then in our case it has 4 edges and 2 sides so in your case the 4 edges were correct but not the sides(top) hence was able to play around with the numbers to get the output.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but lets say I allow the user to input as much text as possible, therefore I will need to adjust the 4th value so that the text would still fit inside div#1, but if I do that I would have to constantly change the 6th value in order to maintain its position at the top. So I can't just play around with the numbers to get the desire output. It needs to be responsive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213591/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-phil-greene).